# TFS 2010 Project Collection Not Listed in VS 2012

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

I recently installed Visual Studio 2012 (RTM) and a project collection is missing from the Team Project Collections list in the "Connect to Team Foundation Server" modal window. The project collection is listed in VS 2008 and VS 2010. The collection state in TFS Administration Console shows as online. This is not a recently created collection it is over 2 years old with many projects. Share Point, Web Access, and Reporting Services sites all work fine. I have run Best Practices Analyzer and did not see anything that stood out although it contained a lot of information and I could have overlooked something. We are running TFS 2010 which was upgraded from TFS 2008.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can't connect to your TFS server at all? or just a particular project?

Comment: I can connect to TFS and see the other 10 collections and access their projects just fine. Just one of the collections is not being listed.

Comment: do you definitely have access to the project from the TFS Administrator?

Comment: I am in the role TFS Server Administrator and can see and edit the collection and any project in VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, where the project collection was listed, but as soon as I attempted to connect to it, the Team Explorer panel showed a 404 error message.

I resolved it by clearing the TFS cache folders under my user profile local app data folder.

In Windows Explorer, go to %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation.  For my profile, there were 3 folders: 2.0, 3.0 and 4.0 (presumably corresponding to TFS 2008, 2010 and 2012) with a Cache folder under each.  I cleared all 3 Cache folders and was then able to connect successfully.